# Python compileall : Bad magic number in .pyc file

Tags: python-3.x, compilation

im compiling a python script like it:

```
python3 -m compileall script.py
```

im using `python3.7`
but if any one runs this script in other python version this problem hapens

```
RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file
```

there is any way to compile for any python3 version ?
or how to fix it?

Comment: ``compileall`` will compile the script for the current Python version, not all of them. Note that outside of some very specific situations (documented in the ``compileall`` documentation), you do not have to use ``compileall``. Python will automatically compile the appropriate byte code when executing a script.

Comment: but i need to protect my code to pass it to my custommers. how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "protect"? Bytecode does not protect your source-code, it can be decompiled to (roughly) reconstruct your source code.

Comment: do you know how to do that ?